# Large .WAV file is causing my Java game to lag

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, memory, lag

I am trying to write a game in Java to learn more about the language. I have recently added sounds and it was working fine until I added background music .WAV (605MB). I have created a separate thread to run the music and I thought that would help as threads shouldn't affect each other's performance due to separate stack memory. I am fairly new to Java so I would appreciate any suggestions. I can cut the file into smaller pieces and loop through them (the game doesn't lag with smaller .WAV files) but I am curious why one thread is affected by another and what could I do differently. I've read that depending on the file size Java allocates resources to different locations, could that mean something? Please find snippets of code where I define Sound Class to read the file and thread definitions.

```
public class Sound {

Clip clip;
URL soundURL[] = new URL[30]; // store file path

Sound() {
    soundURL[0] = getClass().getResource("/sound/BlueBoyAdventure.wav");
    soundURL[1] = getClass().getResource("/sound/coin.wav");
    soundURL[2] = getClass().getResource("/sound/powerup.wav");
    soundURL[3] = getClass().getResource("/sound/unlock.wav");
    soundURL[4] = getClass().getResource("/sound/fanfare.wav");
    soundURL[5] = getClass().getResource("/sound/ChurchTemplarsMusic.wav");
    soundURL[6] = getClass().getResource("/sound/FantasyMusic.wav");
    soundURL[7] = getClass().getResource("/sound/DevilEyes.wav");
}

public void setFile(int i) {
    
    try {
        
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL[i]);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(ais);
        
        
    }catch(Exception e) {
        
    }
}

public void play() {
    
    clip.start();
}

public void loop() {
    
    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}

public void stop() {
    
    clip.stop();
    
}
}
```

First thread (gameEngine):

```
public void run() {
    
    double drawInterval = 1000000000/FPS;
    double delta = 0;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long currentTime;
    long timer = 0;
    int drawCount = 0;
    
    while(gameThread != null) 
    {
        
        currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        
        delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
        timer += (currentTime - lastTime);
        lastTime = currentTime;
        
        if(delta >= 1) {
        update();
        repaint();
        delta--;
        drawCount++;
        }
        if(timer >= 1000000000) {
            System.out.println("FPS:" + drawCount + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            drawCount = 0;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Second thread dedicated to music:

```
public class SecondThread implements Runnable {

Thread musicThread;

//SOUND
Sound sound = new Sound();

  
  public void startMusicThread() {
        
        musicThread = new Thread(this);
        musicThread.setName("Music");
        musicThread.start();
     
  }

@Override
public void run() {

        sound.setFile(7);
        sound.play();
        sound.loop();       
}
```

and this is where I call threads:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    SecondThread secondThread = new SecondThread();

    gamePanel.startGameThread();
    secondThread.startMusicThread();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a truly enormous background music file.

> I have created a separate thread to run the music and I thought that would help as threads shouldn't affect each other's performance due to separate stack memory.

Yes, threads have separate stack memory.  But your music isn't going into stack memory, it's going to the heap, and the heap is common to the whole JVM -- every thread is going to be using the same heap.  (How else could threads access each other's variables?)

You have correctly identified the solution, to break up the background music into smaller parts and load only one or two parts at once.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I thought there would be some other way to go around it! Cheers

Comment: The pairing of an `AudioInputStream` with a `SourceDataLine` accomplishes incremental reads and writes.

Answer (score 0):

WAV usually is non-compressed PCM audio data. Your 650 MB is similar to an audio CD, which typically holds one hour of music. If you compress that using MP3 (or even better as OGG), you might roughly get down to 65 MB while keeping an acceptable quality.

I am not sure whether those 65 MB would be sufficiently small to simply play - but then you could still break it down into different tracks and decide which one to play based on game events.

Comment: Unfortunately, Java doesn't support the playback of compressed audio. An additional library would have to be brought in for that. One library that can handle compressed audio is JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

The `javax.sounds.sampled.Clip` is meant for relatively short sounds that can be held in memory and are likely to be replayed. For a file that is large, you should use `javax.sounds.sampled.SourceDataLine` for playback. This interface is for streaming sounds that are read progressively. In this case, you should use an `AudioInputStream` to read the file and progressively hand off buffer arraysto the `SourceDataLine.write` method.

A `while` loop is commmon for reading and writing in this scenario, and this loop is usually placed in its own thread. There is an example of audio play back using a `SourceDataLine` in the [javasound tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info). A weakness of this example is that it doesn't put the while loop in its own thread, so the program flow will get tied up for the duration of the playback. You'll have to write code to manage that.

You might be unaware that the `Clip` is designed to be loaded and opened only once, and held in memory ready for repeated play backs. Loading and opening prior to each play can add latency that serves no purpose. Also, when a `Clip` is played, it's a fire-and-forget type situation. The playback code is automatically launched in its own (daemon) thread. Wrapping `Clip` playback in an additional thread is a dubious use of resources.